# How to align a set of multiline equations

Tags: equations, align

I am trying to align a set of long equations, that are themselves `align` environments as most of them are spreading on multiple lines.

Currently I just have a sequence of `align` environments, with each equation inside in order to align the pieces of each equations. I am attaching a screenshot of the result:

[image: Unaligned]

What would like to get instead is something looking more like

[image: Aligned]

which is the same set of equations after going through the copyediting office of a journal and looks much better.

Here is a MWE. I would like all three equations to align on the equal sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a & =  b + c + d \nonumber \\
  & \qquad + e + f + g
\label{eq:1}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
k & = l + m + n + m + n + m + n \nonumber \\
  & \qquad + o + p + q
\label{eq:2}
\end{align}
\begin{equation}
r = s + t (u + v + w)
\label{eq:3}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you provided the code in terms of a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Perhaps [How to align across ordinary text; as in breaking matrices, sets of equations, tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43494/how-to-align-across-ordinary-text-as-in-breaking-matrices-sets-of-equations/43512#43512) might be a useful.

Comment: I think it's better to use `split` for single long equations rather than `align`. according to the document, `split` is for single long equations, `align` is for multiple equations. The numbering should be affected.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

without an actual example, here's how i interpret what you want.

[image: output of example code]

and here is the input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
This example shows \verb|aligned| equations within
an \verb|align| environment.
\begin{align}
  \phantom{i + j + k}
  &\begin{aligned}
    \mathllap{a} &= b + c + d\\
      &\qquad + e + f + g + x + y + z
  \end{aligned}\\
  &\begin{aligned}
    \mathllap{i + j + k} &= l + m + n\\
      &\qquad + o + p + q
  \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

the longest left-hand element is inserted at the beginning as a `\phantom`
and the lengths of the left-hand elements of the individual `aligned` segments
are made "invisible" by lapping them to the left using `\mathllap` from the
`mathtools` package.

the original answer was (correctly) noted to align the segments properly
only when the left-hand sides had the same length.  this modification
overcomes that problem.

Comment: oops!  forgot a couple of ampersands.  updated version coming up.

Comment: only works if the left hand sides have the same lengths?

Comment: @user1834164 -- you're correct about the lengths of the left-hand elements.  but it can be salvaged.  adding that ...

Comment: why do we need   \phantom{i + j + k}.. I could not understand..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik -- the `\phantom` is needed so that the width of the left-hand side of the group of equations is included in the width of the whole group, so that the group will be centered.

Answer (score 102):

You can also use the `split` environment inside the `align` environment, using an ampersand (`&`) where you want the alignment to take place. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}\label{eq:1}
    a ={}& b + c + d\\
         & + e + f + g
\end{split}\\
\begin{split}\label{eq:2}
    k ={}& l + m + n + m + n + m + n\\
         & + o + p + q
\end{split}\\
    r ={}& s + t (u + v + w)\label{eq:3}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Notice that the last equation is not inside a `split` environment, but still aligns with the rest, since it's still inside the `align` environment.

The output looks like this:

[image: Output of a split environment inside an align environment]

Note the empty groups (`{}`) before the ampersands. Without these, there would be no kerning applied between the equals signs and the character afterwards, because the alignment breaks the box. While the empty groups don't do anything themselves, in math mode the symbols before them add kerning as though the empty groups were ordinary characters. This enables TeX to choose the most appropriate spacing. If the ampersands were placed before the equal signs, the align environment would kern around the equal signs as it should with no such hassle, but then the addition sign of the split equation would lie uncomfortably far back, requiring some sort of manual tweaking of its own.

Comment: The nice thing about thing about this solution is that there is no need to mess around with `\phantom` or `\mathllap`.

Comment: Wow! In fact, it seems that you don't even need the splits, replacing `&=` with `={}&` does the trick!

Comment: When I try to do that, I get the error "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr." I get this error when I try to use more than one ampersand within split. Any ideas?

Comment: @Blaisorblade -- the reason for the splits is to properly apply the equation numbers to each group.  yes, `\notag` could be used, but it doesn't give the desired output if the equation number should be centered on the group.

Comment: I tried this technique and it worked when converting to PDF, but malfunctioned when converting to HTML using the `mk4ht htlatex test.tex "xhtml,mathml"` workflow.  I assume it's a bug in the html converter.

Answer (score 32):

As an extension to barbara's answer, you could wrap only the right-hand side of your equations into `aligned` subenvironments. This allows you to align the equal signs of the separate equations independent of the size of left- or right-hand sides.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
This example shows \verb|aligned| equations within
an \verb|align| environment.
\begin{align}
  a &= \begin{aligned}[t]
      &b + c + d +\\
      &c + e + f + g + h + i
       \end{aligned}\\
  k &= \begin{aligned}[t]
      &l + m + n\\
      &+ o + p + q
       \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The plus sign on the second line of the second equation does not exactly match up because it's a `mathbin` symbol. Maybe someone with more TeX knowledge could comment on how to best fix that.

Comment: Thanks, that works too. The difference I see is that equation numbers are on the top line of each equation, whereas when the whole equation is in the 'aligned' environment the equation numbers are vertically centred. Is there a way to control that?

Comment: @eldering -- to get the matching spacing after the first plus sign in the last line, precede it by an empty group, `{}`.

Answer (score 28):

Here is an `align`-only version of your equations:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\myvec}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}% Vector notation
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  f_{\textit{P},\textit{P}}\left(\myvec{n};\myvec{m}\right) &= \frac{\omega^2}{4\pi\rho\alpha^4} \textit{AF}\left(k_\alpha\left(\myvec{n}-\myvec{m}\right)\right) \nonumber \\
    &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \times\left\{\left(\lambda+\mu\right)^2\eta_N+\left(\lambda+\mu\right)\mu\eta_N\left(\cos 2\phi+\cos 2\theta\right)\right. \nonumber \\
    &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace +\;\mu^2\eta_N\cos 2\phi\cos 2\theta+\mu^2\eta_T\sin 2\phi\sin 2\theta\cos\varphi\vphantom{\left(\lambda\right)^2}\right\}, \\
  f_{\textit{P},\textit{SH}}\left(\myvec{n};\myvec{m},\myvec{q}\right) &= \frac{\omega^2}{4\pi\rho\alpha\beta^3} \textit{AF}\left(k_\alpha\myvec{n}-k_\beta\myvec{m}\right) \nonumber \\
    &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \times\left(-\mu^2\eta_T\right)\sin 2\phi\cos\theta\sin\varphi, \\
  f_{\textit{P},\textit{SV}}\left(\myvec{n};\myvec{m},\myvec{q}\right) &= \frac{\omega^2}{4\pi\rho\alpha\beta^3} \textit{AF}\left(k_\alpha\myvec{n}-k_\beta\myvec{m}\right) \nonumber \\
    &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \times\left\{\left(\lambda+\mu\right)\mu\eta_N\sin 2\theta+\mu^2\eta_N\cos 2\phi\sin 2\theta\right. \nonumber \\
    &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace -\;\mu^2\eta_T\sin 2\phi\cos 2\theta\cos\varphi\right\},
\end{align}
\end{document}
​
```

Some of the adjustments include

- Using `\mathrel` for proper spacing around hidden `=` (included via `\phantom`);
- Some negative `\nulldelimiter` kerning around missing `\left.` delimiters (otherwise there would be additional spacing introduced between operator/operand);
- Height adjustment for multi-line `\left\{` and `\right\}` pairs.

As a common thread, it may be useful to peruse Herbert Voß' [`mathmode` document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf).

Answer (score 12):

This is a way to accomplish this for small amounts of text by using the `\intertext` command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
This example shows \verb|aligned| equations within
an \verb|align| environment.
\begin{align}
  \begin{aligned}
a &= b + c + d\\
  &\qquad + e + f + g
  \end{aligned}\\
  \begin{aligned}
k &= l + m + n + m + n + m + n\\
  &\qquad + o + p + q
  \end{aligned}
\end{align}

This example shows text and  equations within
an \verb|align| environment.
\begin{align}
a &= b + c + d\\
  &\qquad + e + f + g
\intertext{A small amount of text can go here with $x=2$ inline math
 and     $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=F(b)-F(a)$$ (even inline math). But not a lot 
of text. }
k &= l + m + n + m + n + m + n\\
  &\qquad + o + p + q
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The relevant part is about `\qquad`, which I've used, but that doesn't work well enough.

Comment: (+1) Ah! :) I was looking for such a thing for a while. Many thanks. :)

Comment: In case of paragraphs splitting the equations to be aligned, what is the best solution?

Answer (score 9):

If instead of aligning the trailing equations you wish to right-justify them (similarly to the way the `\multiline` environment handles trailing equations), you can use the following trick, which I picked up from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83524) by Ulrike Fischer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a & = b + c + d + e + f + g + h \nonumber \\
  & \hspace{7cm} + i + j + k \\
a & = b + c + d + e + f + g + h \nonumber \\
  & \omit\hfill ${} + i + j + k$
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: omit + hfill]

Answer (score 2):

This answer works when you use the `fleqn` package. The example below defines two LaTeX macros `\mymidline` and `\mylastline`. Both macros essentially expand to their first argument within `align*` environments. The `\mymidline` macro centers it and the `\mylastline` macro right-aligns it. Thereby, the width of the stuff in the second argument is subtracted from the available "display width". For `align*` environments that should just be the (longest) left-hand side of the equation. The example below shows how you can do that most efficiently with a macro `\LHS`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[DIV15]{typearea}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{fleqn}
\usepackage{ulem}
\makeatletter
\newdimen\@tzadima
\newdimen\@tzadimb
\newbox\@tzaboxa
\def\mylinemeasures#1#2{%
  \@tzadima\displaywidth%
  \advance\@tzadima-\tagwidth@%
  \advance\@tzadima-\alignsep@%
  \setbox\@tzaboxa\hbox{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \@tzadimb\wd\@tzaboxa%
  \advance\@tzadima-\@tzadimb%
  \setbox\@tzaboxa\hbox{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \@tzadimb\wd\@tzaboxa%
  \advance\@tzadima-\@tzadimb%
}
\def\mymidline#1#2{%
  \mylinemeasures{#1}{#2}%
  \divide\@tzadima2%
  \hbox to \@tzadima{}#1\notag
}
\def\mylastline#1#2{%
  \mylinemeasures{#1}{#2}%
  \hbox to \@tzadima{}#1%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \gdef\LHS{(L\cdot R)^{(i)}[i+1:n,i+1:n]}\LHS
  &= \underbrace{L^{(i-1)}[i+1:n,1:i-1]\cdot R^{(i-1)}[1:i-1,i+1:n]}_{\text{untouched}}+\\
  &\mymidline{+ L^{(i)}[i+1:n,i] \underbrace{R^{(i)}[i,i+1:n]}_{\text{untouched pivot row}}+}\LHS\\
  &\mylastline{+ \underbrace{L^{(i)}[i+1:n,i+1:n]}_{=1_{n-i-1}}\cdot R^{(i)}[i+1:n,i+1:n]}\LHS\\
  &= L^{(i-1)}[i+1:n,1:i-1]\cdot R^{(i-1)}[1:i-1,i+1:n]
    +\\
  &\mymidline{+ \uwave{L^{(i)}[i+1:n,i]\cdot R^{(i-1)}[i,i+1:n]}+}\LHS\\
  &\mylastline{+R^{(i-1)}[i+1:n,i+1:n]\uwave{\strut- L^{(i)}[i+1:n,i]\cdot R^{(i-1)}[i,i+1:n]}}\LHS\\
  &=L^{(i-1)}[i+1:n,1:i-1]\cdot R^{(i-1)}[1:i-1,i+1:n] +\\
  &\mymidline{+ \underbrace{L^{(i-1)}[i+1:n,i]}_{=0}\cdot R^{(i-1)}[i,i+1:n] +}\LHS\\
  &\mylastline{+ \underbrace{L^{(i-1)}[i+1:n,i+1:n]}_{=1_{n-i}}\cdot R^{(i-1)}[i+1:n,i+1:n]}\LHS\\
  &= A[i+1:n,i+1:n].
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Multline like formatting within align*]

If you have the numbered version `align*` you should also consider the width of the equation label and the label separator in the second argument of `\mymidline` and `\mylastline`.
I didn't find a predefined measure for the label width. After some tests it turned out that `\quad\quad(1)` is an appropriate placeholder for the label.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[DIV15]{typearea}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{fleqn}
\usepackage{ulem}
\makeatletter
\newdimen\@tzadima
\newdimen\@tzadimb
\newbox\@tzaboxa
\def\mylinemeasures#1#2{%
  \@tzadima\displaywidth%
  \advance\@tzadima-\tagwidth@%
  \advance\@tzadima-\alignsep@%
  \setbox\@tzaboxa\hbox{$\displaystyle#1$}%
  \@tzadimb\wd\@tzaboxa%
  \advance\@tzadima-\@tzadimb%
  \setbox\@tzaboxa\hbox{$\displaystyle#2$}%
  \@tzadimb\wd\@tzaboxa%
  \advance\@tzadima-\@tzadimb%
}
\def\mymidline#1#2{%
  \mylinemeasures{#1}{#2}%
  \divide\@tzadima2%
  \hbox to \@tzadima{}#1\notag
}
\def\mylastline#1#2{%
  \mylinemeasures{#1}{#2}%
  \hbox to \@tzadima{}#1%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \gdef\LHS{(L\cdot R)^{(i)}[i+1:n,i+1:n]}\LHS
  &= \underbrace{L^{(i-1)}[i+1:n,1:i-1]\cdot R^{(i-1)}[1:i-1,i+1:n]}_{\text{untouched}}+\notag\\
  &\mymidline{+ L^{(i)}[i+1:n,i] \underbrace{R^{(i)}[i,i+1:n]}_{\text{untouched pivot row}}+}\LHS\\
  &\mylastline{+ \underbrace{L^{(i)}[i+1:n,i+1:n]}_{=1_{n-i-1}}\cdot R^{(i)}[i+1:n,i+1:n]}{\LHS\quad\quad(1)}\\
  &= L^{(i-1)}[i+1:n,1:i-1]\cdot R^{(i-1)}[1:i-1,i+1:n] +\notag\\
  &\mymidline{+ \uwave{L^{(i)}[i+1:n,i]\cdot R^{(i-1)}[i,i+1:n]}+}{(L\cdot R)^{(i)}[i+1:n,i+1:n]}\\
  &\mylastline{+R^{(i-1)}[i+1:n,i+1:n]\uwave{\strut- L^{(i)}[i+1:n,i]\cdot R^{(i-1)}[i,i+1:n]}}{\LHS\quad\quad(1)}\\
  &=L^{(i-1)}[i+1:n,1:i-1]\cdot R^{(i-1)}[1:i-1,i+1:n] +\notag\\
  &\mymidline{+ \underbrace{L^{(i-1)}[i+1:n,i]}_{=0}\cdot R^{(i-1)}[i,i+1:n] +}{(L\cdot R)^{(i)}[i+1:n,i+1:n]}\\
  &\mylastline{+ \underbrace{L^{(i-1)}[i+1:n,i+1:n]}_{=1_{n-i}}\cdot R^{(i-1)}[i+1:n,i+1:n]}{\LHS\quad\quad(1)}\\
  &= A[i+1:n,i+1:n].
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{align}
\ni Tdij (Ti,Tj,Sk,t) & = Tdij(Ti,Tj,Sk,t) \nonumber \\
 & Tddir (Ti,Tj,Sk,t) \bigoplus \nonumber \\
& Tdrecom (Ti,Tj,Sk,t) \bigoplus \nonumber \\
& Tdiv (Ti,Tj,Sk,t)
\label{eq:1}
\end{align}
```

will provide following output
[image]

Comment: How does this address the original post in such a way that hasn't already been addressed by the other answers?