# Spacing after equals sign in align

Tags: math-mode, align

I find that I have unpleasant spacing between the equals sign and (e.g.) the exponential function in this particular case, while using the `align` environment. I have a long expression which has to be split up in multiple rows. The alignment character `&` appears to gobble up all space when it comes after the equals sign. How could I remedy this while still preserving the plus sign alignment below?

Ideally, I would like to have the second row from the first equation, and the first row from the second equation.

[image: Compiled document]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align} % bad spacing at first row, but correctly placed second row
    2 \cosh t =& e^t \\
            &+ e^{-t} 
\end{align}
\begin{align} % good spacing at first row, but incorrectly placed second row
    2\cosh t &= e^t \\
            &+ e^{-t} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! To get the correct spacing around the `=` sign, one *must* write `&=` rather than `=&`.

Comment: Similar question: [How to align a set of multiline equations - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/how-to-align-a-set-of-multiline-equations/44465#44465)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put the ampersand before the equals sign. Then use `\quad` to create the indentation in the second row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}                                                                   
    2 \cosh t &= e^t \\                                                         
              &\quad+ e^{-t}                                                    
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

You can also use `\hspace` if you want a different length for the indentation.

[image: alignment]

Comment: Wouldn't `\begin{align}                                                                   
    2 \cosh t &= e^t \\                                                         
              &\phantom{{}={}} + e^{-t}                                                    
\end{align}` be better? Then the plus symbol would be inset by the width of the equals sign, with the correct spacing.

Comment: I'd say it's a matter of taste.

Comment: @Niel de Beaudrap: You are missing a `\negmedspace` for correct spacing: `2 \cosh t &= e^t \\ &\phantom{{}={}} \negmedspace + e^{-t}`

Answer (score 10):

I wouldn't try aligning the plus with `e^t`, but if you insist, here's how.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\noindent
The plus is flush with $e^t$ (I wouldn't recommend it):
\begin{align}
2\cosh t ={}& e^t \\
            & \negmedspace+ e^{-t}
\end{align}
The plus is moved right (better):
\begin{align}
2\cosh t &= e^t \\
         &\qquad+ e^{-t}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

With `\negmedspace` we kill the space at the left of the binary operation symbol.

[image]

However, `align` is the wrong tool here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
2\cosh t &= e^t \\
         &\qquad + e^{-t}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for recommending `split`

Answer (score 5):

You have placed the `&` in an odd position, I think; it's "smarter" to put it in front of the equal sign to get the correct spacing. Also, I've used `\hphantom` to indent the expression in the second line to get the correct alignment. (Notice the `{}` before `=`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
   2\cosh t
   &= e^{t} \\
   &\hphantom{{}=} + e^{-t} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: It is not wrong, one just have to be a bit more careful. Besides ` = {} &` is a lot short to type than `&\hphantom{{}=}` ;-)

Comment: @daleif Good point. The reason why I used `\hphantom` is that it's more 'universal'.

Comment: I had to use <\hphantom{{}={}}>, since your solution still made the second line start a bit too early...

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you wish to ensure that the two instances of `e` are aligned vertically, while respecting the fact that a binary operator (`+`) precedes the `e` in the second row. The most direct way to obtain this type of alignment is to use a pair of `\hphantom` ("horizonal phantom") statements. The one in the first row mimics the `+` symbol (a binary operator) from the second row, and the `\hphantom` statement in the second row mimics the `=` symbol (a relational operator) from the first row. The `{}` pairs are there to help TeX figure out which type of operator applies.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength\textwidth{3in} %% just for this example
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    2\cosh t &= \phantom{{}+{}} \mathrm{e}^t \\
             &\phantom{{}={}} + \mathrm{e}^{-t}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, only the first part of egreg's answer and Niel de Beaudrap's modified comment solve the problem as intended by Martin L. All other answers require space corrections of at least 1 or 2 mu. Here is an alternative.

LaTeX encloses relation symbols in thick spaces `\;` and binary operator symbols in medium spaces `\:`. The symbols `=` and `+` in our example are each of this type. Therefore, downgrading them to ordinary symbols, what we want is:

```
2 \cosh t & \; \mathord{=} \; e^t \\
          & \; \phantom{=} \; \mathord{+} \: e^{-t}
```

A practical incarnation of the above is (see page 36 of [l2kurz.pdf](https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/info/lshort/german/l2kurz.pdf)):

```
2 \cosh t & = e^{t} \\
          & \phantom{=} \  + e^{-t}
```

The `\phantom` command strips `=` of its relation status, leaving it short of two thick spaces. On the other hand, LaTeX interprets `+` as a binary operator, creating a spurious medium space. So we need an extra normal space: `\  = \; + \; - \:`.

[image]