# LyX Spacing after = sign in \align

Tags: spacing, lyx, align

My question is the same as [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212605/spacing-after-equals-sign-in-align), but in the context of LyX. The solution for that question was to put the & before = sign.

I manually implemented this tweak in LyX, by changing the raw math code (see below).

**My question is this: How do I change the \align environment in LyX so that it automatically accomplishes this tweak every time I use the \align environment? (Instead of having to manually change the raw code for every instance as I did here.)**

What I did in LyX:

[image]

What the output PDF looks like:

[image]

What the TeX code looks like:

```
\begin{document}
Default \LyX{} align Environment:

\begin{alignat*}{1}
x= & y\\
= & z
\end{alignat*}


Tweaked (to get desired result):

\begin{alignat*}{1}
x & =y\\
 & =z
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

In response to a comment, I tried putting the "=" sign at all possible positions. Here are the 4 permutations.

[image]

The result is not as desired:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the `align*` environment? `alignat` is made for more than one alignment group.

Comment: @Bernard: To be honest, I don't know what the difference is. I happened to use alignat when I first used LyX and that's what I've used ever since. I can perceive no difference between the two. The same problem (described in my above question) still occurs when I use align.

Comment: if lyx is putting the `&` *after* the `=`, then lyx is wrong, and a report should be made to the maintainers.  (the recommended/required order is documented in the user's guide for `amsmath`.  that manual also describes the difference between `allign` and `alignat`.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton LyX doesn't put the `=` anywhere, the user does, so if it ends up the wrong side of the `&` it's because the user entered the `=` in the wrong column. Kenny:  Put the `=` in the second column.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Please see the two screenshots I added and let me know what you think. I have tried putting the = sign at all possible positions and it is still not as desired.

Comment: `alignat` isn't designed for setting `a=y=a` it is designed for `a=y   b=x`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. -- i'm not a lyx user, but if the spacing is different on the two sides of an `=` sign, and the `&` precedes the `=` sign, then lyx isn't doing what tex is designed to do.  the spacing in the presence of `&` is supposed to be *exactly* the same as the spacing for `a = b` (assuming math mode).

Comment: @barbarabeeton LyX does the right thing (it generates LaTeX code and compiles that to get a PDF, and as far as I can see the correct code is generated in this case).

Comment: Kenny: Can you try to explain exactly what kind of alignment you want to achieve?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. -- okay.  since the code isn't shown for the `a = y = b` example, i must assume that *all* are input improperly.  (certainly something is out of kilter.)

Comment: is there any news?  if not, this question is likely to be closed as unclear.