# spacing after "equals" sign in align environment

Tags: align, environments

Sometimes I want to use `align` in this fashion:

```
\begin{align}
 & A\\
=& B\\
=& C
\end{align}
```

But latex flushes A, B, C against the equals sign, and I end up having to type something like this instead:

```
\begin{align}
 &\,\, A\\
=&\,\, B\\
=&\,\, C
\end{align}
```

Is there a "best practice" solution to avoid the use of `\,`, while visually achieving the same result as the second piece of code?

(Nb: I have checked that this is not a duplicate of: [Spacing after equals sign in align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212605/spacing-after-equals-sign-in-align))

Comment: in what way is it not a duplicate of the question that you reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\begin{align}
 & A\\
={}& B\\
={}& C
\end{align}
```

placing the `=` to the left of the `&` and space to the right does not work as you would still have incorrect space to the left of the =, adding the empty `{}` math atom allows the = to have `\mathrel` spacing.

Comment: Thanks! Because an empty pair `{}` is so fast to type, this is convenient...

Answer (score 3):

Hum... in the meanwhile of writing up my question, I found that

```
\begin{align}
&\phantom{{}={}} A\\
&= B\\
&= C
\end{align}
```

work as desired. (I guess this is best practice?)

Comment: It's certainly what I do:)

Comment: With the original setup, it is faster to just type ` {} & `, the `=` sees the empty token (`{} `) and inserts the proper spacing

Comment: @daleif: Didn't quite understand what you were saying, maybe because of typos in your comment... did you mean the same as David Carlisle's comment below?

Comment: It was, not sure was went wrong in the comment. Nevermind

Answer (score 1):

If A, B or C is an expression beginning with a binary or prefix operator like `-` or `\sum`, then the previous answers give incorrect spacings. But the following solution will work.

The `\phantom` command downgrades a relation to an ordinary symbol. We therefore also define a relational phantom command `\rphantom` that preserves the class of a relation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\rphantom}[1]{\mathrel{\phantom{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
   &\rphantom{=} -A\\
   &= B\\
   &= -C-D\\
   &\phantom{=}\ -E
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

A binary operator like `-` following a relation like `=` or `\rphantom{=}` is interpreted by LaTeX as an ordinary symbol. That's what we want in the first and the third line of our example.

LaTeX encloses relation symbols in thick spaces `\;` and binary operator symbols in medium spaces `\:`. In the fourth line of our example, the `\phantom` command strips `=` of its relation status, leaving it short of two thick spaces. On the other hand, LaTeX interprets `-` as a binary operator, creating a spurious medium space. So we need an extra normal space: `\  = \; + \; - \:`.

[image]