# Aligning Multiline Matrix Equations

Tags: align, amsmath, multline

I need to align two equations, one of which spans two lines.

I've tried the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/how-to-align-a-set-of-multiline-equations), but this isn't for matrix equations, and it doesn't seem to work with these.

My minimized code is:

```
\begin{align}           %start alignment between state and observation equation 
%State Equation
\begin{split}           %split the observation equation in two so it fits on the page
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{bmatrix}
&=                    %This & is to align the state and observation equation
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
b&c\\
d&e
\end{bmatrix}
&                        %This & is to align the splitted state equation
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{bmatrix}\\           %This \\is to split the state equation
+
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\ 
b&c\\ 
c&d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c\\
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}
&a                         %This & is to align the splitted state equation
\end{split} \\             %This \\ is to split the state and observation equation
%Observation Equation
a &=                       %This & is to align the state and observation equation
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
```

I've minimized the code slightly in the above example for readability. But my actual output looks like this:

[image]

Annoyingly equation 5.17 (The state equation) splits into 3 instead of into 2 so it fits on the page. I also get the error `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.`

How do I get it so equation 5.17 is split into two, and also equation 5.17 and 5.18 are aligned?

**Desired look**

[image]

But with less space between the two parts of the state equation (5.17)

Comment: What should the desired look like? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The split is redundant to the align.  Simply use \notag to avoid putting an equation number on any particular line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}           %start alignment between state and observation equation 
%State Equation
%\begin{split}           %split the observation equation in two so it fits on the page
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{bmatrix}
&=                    %This & is to align the state and observation equation
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
b&c\\
d&e
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{bmatrix} \notag \\ %split here
&\quad +
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\ 
b&c\\ 
c&d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c\\
\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix} a
\\             %This \\ is to split the state and observation equation
%Observation Equation
a &=                       %This & is to align the state and observation equation
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: matrix equations]

Comment: Does `\notag` completely remove the number, or does it just not display it? i.e, will this mess up the ordering of the other equations?

Comment: The number is neither used, displayed nor incremented.  \label will not work on \notag, nor will it appear in a list of equations.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\ b\\ c
\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}
               a & b & c \\ e & f & g \\ h & i & j
               \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
                            ab \\ cd \\ ef
                            \end{bmatrix} \\
&\phantom{aaaaaa}+\begin{bmatrix}
                  a & b \\ c & d \\ e & f
                 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
                               ab \\ cd \\ ef
                              \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
                                             a \\ b
                                            \end{bmatrix}X 
\end{split}\\
Y&=\begin{bmatrix}
   a & b
   \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
                c \\ d
                \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! Can I just ask, apart from the use of the phantom a, how is this different from the code I gave in the question? I can see that yours works and mine doesn't, but I cant see why.

Comment: Well, your code makes error in online compiler :v ... I just create a new code. In your code there are `&` after second `bmatrix`, because that the third matrix appear out of place ...

Comment: You can mark my response like solution :v ...