# Multipling matrices over a number of lines

Tags: equations, matrices

I am currently having a problem with multiplying matrices over a number of lines, my code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}


\begin{align*}
= \min tr \left \{ \begin{bmatrix}
d_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
0 & d_2 & \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots  & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & d_p\\ 
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix} \left (\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots  & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots  & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right ) \\
 \begin{bmatrix}
d_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
0 & d_2 & \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots  & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & d_p\\ 
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
 \left(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots  & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\ 
\vdots  & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right) \right \}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Ideally I would want all of them in the same line, but since they are too long, I have to use multiple lines. 
It seems like the problem might be with the curly bracket at the end.

I have tried to implement what is suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245519/aligning-multiline-matrix-equations) and have also tried using `multiline`, but have not been successful.

I am fairly new to latex, so apologies if this question has a very simple answer. 
Thank you!

Comment: you can not break the line between \left and \right, use `\bigl\{  and \bigr\}  also please post the example in a form that we can run without guessing the needed preamble and page size.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle I have added the preamble and page size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that this is part of a bigger display. Since all objects have the same height, you can use `\right.` and `\left.` to insert “empty delimiters”.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&= \min \operatorname{tr}
\left \{
  \begin{bmatrix}
  d_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
  0 & d_2 & \cdots & 0\\ 
  \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\ 
  0 & 0 & 0 & d_p\\ 
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
  \left(
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\ 
    \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
    0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
    \end{bmatrix} -
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\ 
    \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
    \end{bmatrix}
  \right )
\right.
\\
&\hspace{6em}\left.
  \begin{bmatrix}
  d_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
  0 & d_2 & \cdots & 0\\ 
  \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\ 
  0 & 0 & 0 & d_p\\ 
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
  \end{bmatrix} 
  \left(
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\ 
    \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
    0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
    \end{bmatrix} -
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\ 
    \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots\\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
    \end{bmatrix}
  \right)
\right \}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @egreg this answers my question, really appreciate it!