# How to align two sets of equation separated by some text in a beamer slide?

Tags: beamer, equations, align

I want to align the two set of equations on same slide.

I found a similar post [How to align a set of multiline equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/how-to-align-a-set-of-multiline-equations) but there the equations do not involve text as in this case

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle {MWE:Align two set of equations}
\begin{center}
\begin{align*}
\sigma^2&=(a+b)^2-(a+c)^2 \\
        &=(a^2+b^2-2ab)-(a^2+c^2-2ac) 
\end{align*}
\end{center}
Cancel out common terms, then
\begin{center}
\begin{equation}
\sigma^2= b^2-c^2+2(ac-ab) 
\end{equation}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Green arrow shows where I would like my eq 2 to appear.

[image]

Comment: Why have you included `tikz`?

Comment: By mistake....Edited it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`amsmath` provides `\intertext{}` for this kind of purpose. For example,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle {MWE:  Align two set of equations}
    \begin{align*}
      \sigma^2&=(a+b)^2-(a+c)^2 \\
      &=(a^2+b^2-2ab)-(a^2+c^2-2ac)\\
      \intertext{Cancel out common terms, then}
      \sigma^2&= b^2-c^2+2(ac-ab)
    \end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: intertext]

Comment: Doesn't work with me. The text appears in the middle, not on the left as in your example. Maybe Beamer is the problem.