# Split equations inside the align environment

Tags: split

I have some equations that I have written inside the `align` environment. Because some of these equations are rather long, they tend to spill over the page. I have tried using the `split` environment inside the `align` environment to split some of these equations over two lines but this appears to break the code. I would be very grateful for some advice on how to modify my code in order to achieve the desired outcome. My (original) code and the output produced by LaTeX are shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\dot{v}       & = \dfrac{1}{m}[T\cos\beta\cos(\alpha+\epsilon)-D]-g\sin\gamma +\dot{w}_{x} \cos\gamma\cos\chi+\dot{w}_{y}\cos\gamma\sin\chi \\[2pt]
\dot{\gamma}  & = \dfrac{1}{m}[(Y-T\sin\beta\cos(\alpha+\epsilon))\sin\mu + (T\sin(\alpha +\epsilon)+L)\cos\mu] - \dfrac{g}{v}\cos\gamma +\dfrac{1}{v}[\dot{w}_{x}\sin\gamma\cos\chi + \dot{w}_{y}\sin\gamma\sin\chi] \\[2pt]
\dot{\chi}    & = \dfrac{1}{mv\cos\gamma}[(L+T\sin(\alpha+\epsilon) )\sin\mu + (T\sin\beta \cos(\alpha  + \epsilon) - Y)\cos\mu] + \dfrac{1}{v\cos\gamma}[\dot{w}_{x}\sin\chi-\dot{w}_{y}\cos\chi] 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `multline` command? See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/253965/117534

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/how-to-align-a-set-of-multiline-equations) may also be helpful, it seems to be a similar issue, of using `multline` but with aligning.

Comment: The simplest thing to do is just break where appropriate and begin the continuation line with `&\qquad`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use `split` inside `align`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
  \dot{v}     & = \dfrac{1}{m}[T\cos\beta\cos(\alpha+\epsilon)-D]-g\sin\gamma \\
              &\qquad +\dot{w}_{x} \cos\gamma\cos\chi+\dot{w}_{y}\cos\gamma\sin\chi
\end{split}
\\[2ex]
\begin{split}
\dot{\gamma}  & = \dfrac{1}{m}[(Y-T\sin\beta\cos(\alpha+\epsilon))\sin\mu \\
              &\qquad + (T\sin(\alpha +\epsilon)+L)\cos\mu] - \dfrac{g}{v}\cos\gamma \\
              &\qquad +\dfrac{1}{v}[\dot{w}_{x}\sin\gamma\cos\chi + \dot{w}_{y}\sin\gamma\sin\chi]
\end{split}
\\[2ex]
\begin{split}
\dot{\chi}    & = \dfrac{1}{mv\cos\gamma}[(L+T\sin(\alpha+\epsilon) )\sin\mu \\
              &\qquad + (T\sin\beta \cos(\alpha  + \epsilon) - Y)\cos\mu] \\
              &\qquad + \dfrac{1}{v\cos\gamma}[\dot{w}_{x}\sin\chi-\dot{w}_{y}\cos\chi]
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very helpful! In a similar situation where I wanted to use ``\phantom{PREVIOUS LINE}`` instead of ``\qquad`` to get an alignment further to the right, I found that I needed two things: first a ``%`` at the end of the previous line, secondly an extra ``~`` before the ``\phantom`` command. These alignment issues can be challenging at times.

Comment: Can we add a control so that the sign `=` after `\dot{v}`, `\dot{\gamma}`, and `\dot{\chi}` are aligned?

Comment: @Akira They are. See [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wINVo.png) that I got from the very example, just adding the rule.

Comment: Thank you so much your your comment. It works like a charm <3 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn1PJ.png

Comment: @egreg What is \\[2ex] command? I've seen it in a few examples but I cannot find what it does?

Comment: @DavidWaterworth It tells TeX to end the line and to add some vertical space.

Answer (score 5):

Choose manually some suitable points at which the equations can break and add the `\notag` or `\nonumber` command to remove the equation label at that line.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\dot{v}        ={} &\dfrac{1}{m}[T\cos\beta\cos(\alpha+\epsilon)-D]-g\sin\gamma +\dot{w}_{x} \cos\gamma\cos\chi+\dot{w}_{y}\cos\gamma\sin\chi \\[2pt]
\dot{\gamma}   ={} &\dfrac{1}{m}[(Y-T\sin\beta\cos(\alpha+\epsilon))\sin\mu + (T\sin(\alpha +\epsilon)+L)\cos\mu] - \dfrac{g}{v}\cos\gamma \notag\\
                   &{}+\dfrac{1}{v}[\dot{w}_{x}\sin\gamma\cos\chi+ \dot{w}_{y}\sin\gamma\sin\chi] \\[2pt]
\dot{\chi}     ={} &\dfrac{1}{mv\cos\gamma}[(L+T\sin(\alpha+\epsilon) )\sin\mu + (T\sin\beta \cos(\alpha  + \epsilon) - Y)\cos\mu] \notag\\ 
                   &{}+\dfrac{1}{v\cos\gamma}[\dot{w}_{x}\sin\chi-\dot{w}_{y}\cos\chi] 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear 'AboAmmar', many thanks for sharing your solution, this is precisely what I was after. Thanks. Regards

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution with `aligned` and the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm, nccmath}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}% comment if you uncomment \usepackage{geometry}
  \begin{align}
    \dot{v} & = \dfrac{1}{m}[T\cosβ\cos(\alpha+ϵ)-D]-g\sinγ+\dot{w}_{x} \cosγ\cos\chi+\dot{w}_{y}\cosγ\sinχ\!\! \\[2pt]
    \dot{γ} & =\begin{aligned}[t] \dfrac{1}{m}\bigl[(Y-T\sinβ\cos(\alpha+ϵ))\sinμ+ (T\sin(α+ϵ)+L)\cosμ\bigr] \\[-1.2ex]%
    {}- \dfrac{g}{v}\cosγ+\dfrac{1}{v}\bigl[\dot{w}_{x}\sinγ\cosχ+ \dot{w}_{y}\sinγ\sinχ\bigr]\end{aligned} \\[2pt]
    \dot{χ} & =\begin{aligned}[t] \dfrac{1}{mv\cosγ}\bigl[(L+T\sin(\alpha+ϵ) )\sinμ+ (T\sinβ\cos(α+ ϵ) - Y)\cosμ\bigr] \\[-1.2ex]%
    {}+ \dfrac{1}{v\cosγ}\bigl[\dot{w}_{x}\sin\chi-\dot{w}_{y}\cosχ\bigr]\end{aligned}
  \end{align}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that, if you load geometry, you have more sensible outside margins, so you don't need any more `fleqn`:

[image]

Comment: if you're submitting an article for publication in a journal, *don't* use `geometry`.  if the display doesn't fit within the journal's required margins, you're leaving yourself at the mercy of their copyeditors.

Comment: Dear All, Many thanks for sharing your respective solutions. The one provided by 'AboAmmar' is essentially what I was looking to achieve. Kind regards, Bob

Answer (score 5):

You can keep using the `align` environment. At suitable locations, insert `\notag \\ &\qquad` directives to (a) introduce line breaks and (b) provide an alignment anchor for the remaining stub.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\dot{v}       
&= \frac{1}{m}\bigl[T\cos\beta\cos(\alpha+\epsilon)-D\bigr]-g\sin\gamma \notag\\
&\qquad +\dot{w}_x \cos\gamma\cos\chi+\dot{w}_y\cos\gamma\sin\chi \\[2pt]
\dot{\gamma} 
&= \frac{1}{m}\bigl[(Y-T\sin\beta\cos(\alpha+\epsilon))\sin\mu + (T\sin(\alpha +\epsilon)+L)\cos\mu\bigr]\notag\\
&\qquad -\frac{g}{v}\cos\gamma +\frac{1}{v}(\dot{w}_x\sin\gamma\cos\chi + \dot{w}_y\sin\gamma\sin\chi) \\[2pt]
\dot{\chi}    
&= \frac{1}{mv\cos\gamma}\bigl[(L+T\sin(\alpha+\epsilon) )\sin\mu + (T\sin\beta \cos(\alpha  + \epsilon) - Y)\cos\mu\bigr] \notag\\
&\qquad +\frac{1}{v\cos\gamma}(\dot{w}_x\sin\chi-\dot{w}_y\cos\chi)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```