# How to align multiple equations?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I am trying to align three equations using align like this but I am not sure where to put the `&`.

```
p(k+1) = p(k) * P 
         p(k) = p(k-1) * P
                p(k-1) = p(k-2) * P
```

---

Attempt:

```
\begin{align*}
p(k+1) = &p(k) \cdot P \\
p(k) = &p(k-1) \cdot P \\
&p(k-1) = p(k-2) \cdot P
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Similar to [How to align a set of multiline equations - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44450/how-to-align-a-set-of-multiline-equations?rq=1)

Answer (score 8):

Here are two possible ways using `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
p(k+1) &= \begin{aligned}[t] p(k) &\cdot P \\
p(k) &= \begin{aligned}[t]p(k-1)& \cdot P \\
p(k-1) &= p(k-2) \cdot P
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}


\begin{equation*}
p(k+1) = \begin{aligned}[t] p(k) &\cdot P \\
p(k) &= \begin{aligned}[t]p(k-1)& \cdot P \\
p(k-1) &= p(k-2) \cdot P
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I propose these solutions based on a single `alignat`. The second solution aims at centring `\cdot` w.r.t. the = sign (at the cost of a larger spacing around it):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{calc}
    \newcommand{\mycdot}{\makebox[\widthof{${}={}$}]{$\cdot$}}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{alignat*}{2}
    p(k+1) = p(k) &\cdot P \\
                     p(k) &= & p(k-1) & \cdot P \\
     && p(k-1)&= p(k-2) \cdot P
    \end{alignat*}

    \begin{alignat*}{2}
    p(k+1) = p(k) &\mycdot \mathrlap{P} \\
                     p(k) &= & p(k-1) &\mycdot P \\
     && p(k-1)&= p(k-2) \cdot P
    \end{alignat*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The `\phantom` is your friend when such case occurs. I propose the solution based on classical `\eqalign` and `\phantom`.

```
$$\def\={\mathrel{\phantom{=}}}\def\x{\=\phantom{p(k)}\=}
  \eqalign{
   p(k+1) & =  p(k) \cdot P \cr
          &\=  p(k) = p(k-1) \cdot P \cr
          &\x         p(k-1) = p(k-2) \cdot P 
}
$$

\bye
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd use `array` for this. The centered dot wants to be centered, the only phantom is needed to get the same width also in the last case.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{ r *{3}{ >{{}}c<{{}} l } }
p(k+1) = p(k) &\cdot& P \\
         p(k) &  =  & p(k-1) &\cdot& P      &\mathrel{\phantom{=}}\\
              &     & p(k-1) &  =  & p(k-2) &\cdot& P
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]