# 'Aligned' does not work for multiple equations

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, overleaf

I have four equations and the second one is not aligned with the others. I have tried 'aligned' in the code below but it doesn't work as expected.

```
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \min_{w} \quad & \frac{\mu_{s_i}^Tw - r_f}{\sqrt{w^T\sum_{s_i} w}} 
     + \gamma w^T w\\
    \textrm{s.t.} \quad & 1^T w = 1\\
    & 0 \leq w_i \leq 0.5 \quad & \textrm{i = 1,2,..,7}   \\
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
    
    
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \max_{w} \quad & \mu_{s_i}^Tw + \gamma w^T w\\
    \textrm{s.t.} \quad & \sqrt{w^T\sum_{s_i} w} = \sigma_{s_i}\\
      & 1^T w = 1\\
      & 0 \leq w_i \leq 0.5 \quad & \textrm{i = 1,2,..,7}   \\
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
    
    
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \min_{w} \quad & \sqrt{w^T\sum_{s_i} w} + \gamma w^T w\\
    \textrm{s.t.} \quad & \mu_{s_i}^Tw = R_{s_i}\\
      & 1^T w = 1\\
      & 0 \leq w_i \leq 0.5 \quad & \textrm{i = 1,2,..,7}   \\
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
    
   
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \min_{w} \quad & \sqrt{w^T\sum_{s_i} w} + \gamma w^T w\\
    \textrm{s.t.} \quad & 1^T w = 1\\
      & 0 \leq w_i \leq 0.5 \quad & \textrm{i = 1,2,..,7}   \\
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
```

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Equations are centered, your equations does not have the same width and thus are not "aligned" when compared to each other. Btw use `\dots` for the `... ` part

Answer (score 2):

Your equations are completely distinct and are not grouped in one environment. eqs 15, 17, 18 are aligned properly by chance because their widths are equal. here is a simple example (also there are [many tricks and ways](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44450/108724) for doing this):

```
\begin{align}
&\begin{aligned}
\min_{w} \quad & \frac{\mu_{s_i}^Tw - r_f}{\sqrt{w^T\sum_{s_i} w}} 
+ \gamma w^T w\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & 1^T w = 1\\
& 0 \leq w_i \leq 0.5 \quad & \textrm{i = 1,2,..,7}   \\
\end{aligned}\\
&\begin{aligned}
\max_{w} \quad & \mu_{s_i}^Tw + \gamma w^T w\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & \sqrt{w^T\sum_{s_i} w} = \sigma_{s_i}\\
& 1^T w = 1\\
& 0 \leq w_i \leq 0.5 \quad & \textrm{i = 1,2,..,7}   \\
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
```

[image]