# Varying number of columns in multi-equation environment

Tags: equations, amsmath, align, columns

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\expr}[1]{\begin{pmatrix}x_#1\\y_#1\end{pmatrix}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  c = a \cdot b
\end{equation}
\begin{align*}
  a&=\expr{a} & b&=\expr{b}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

which displays like this:

[image: equation + align* environments]

I.e. the first (part of the) equation is centered, the second part is set in two columns with a third of the free space located before, in between and after.

I would like to have the same setup, but with the equation(s) in one environment.

I have tried several combinations of multi-equation environments in amsmath, but without luck. For instance:

```
\begin{align}
  \begin{aligned}
    c = a \cdot b
  \end{aligned} \\
  \nonumber
  \begin{aligned}a&=\expr{a}\end{aligned} & & \begin{aligned}b&=\expr{b}\end{aligned}
\end{align}
```

displays like this:

[image: align environment]

with the two "sub-equations" being fine, but the main equation at the top is not centered. The following:

```
\begin{gather}
  c = a \cdot b \\
  \begin{aligned}
    \nonumber
    a&=\expr{a} & b&=\expr{b}
  \end{aligned}
\end{gather}
```

results in the two "sub-equations" being set too tight:

[image: gather environment]

Comment: I think this is another case where I would recommend using a combination of `\phantom` and/or `\makebox`.  References: [How to align across ordinary text; as in breaking matrices, sets of equations, tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43512/4301), [Sharing alignment between equations in two different items](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29148/4301), [Aligning different parts of an equation with certain spots in the line above](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45574/4301). There probably are many other similar postings on this site.

Comment: You mention in a comment that the actual expressions are much larger; could you show them? The reason I ask is that I see no advantage in having alignments (`a&=...`, `b&=`) unless there is going to be more rows below those lines.

Comment: @morbusg: The ampersands are to get both a and b right-aligned to the equal sign (and their expressions to be left-aligned to the equal sign).

Comment: RolKau: yeah I know, let me rephrase; `$$\displaylines{c = a \cdot b \cr a = \pmatrix{x_a\cr y_a} \hfil b = \pmatrix{x_b\cr y_b} \cr}$$\bye` (that is in plain-tex, so compile with `pdftex`/`xetex`/`luatex`) So my point is, that unless you have something below, you won't gain anything by having an alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is allowed:

```
\begin{gather}
  \begin{align}
    c = a \cdot b
  \end{align} \\
  \begin{align*}
    a&=\expr{a} & b&=\expr{b} &
  \end{align*}
\end{gather}
```

resulting in:

[image: gather+align]

Answer (score 3):

How about

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\expr}[1]{\begin{pmatrix}x_#1\\y_#1\end{pmatrix}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
        &           &   c   &= a \cdot b\\
    a   &=\expr{a}  &       &           & b &=\expr{b}\nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem is: This is not the equation to which I plan to apply it. The right-hand sides are much larger expressions so there'll have to be some overlap between the first and the second (sub-)equation.

Comment: Could you explain the reason for wanting all in one environment?

Comment: Proximity to the original equation; same reason as for using gather instead of multiple equations.