# How to control several animations with one control

Tags: movie15, animate

1. I want to have a common time control (play/stop/rewind/etc) for several items. Such as an animation and a video. Or two animations.
2. And, how do you position the control buttons above the display area?

Comment: I think you probably need to add some minimal code for us to play with. Setting up dummy animations and videos is a lot to ask us.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt I was hoping to find an example like those at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/animations/

Comment: Some minimal work is expected of questions. We'd like to see that you've attempted to do this before asking the community. As it stands, your question has received little attention, probably for this reason. As I said before, you're asking a lot by not including code, and attempting this for yourself necessarily generates code that you can place here.

Comment: This is easy from within Adobe Acrobat Pro if we assume that both videos are from ``external'' sources. How to assign same control to an external video and an internal animation remains to be seen.

Comment: All I can do is reiterate. You should really give us a starting point to work with. For example, an animation would be nice, otherwise we have to construct our own. Same goes for the movie. Point us to a movie somewhere on the net that we can use to test. Those are in addition to a shell document, since we don't know what other packages you'll be using and those may have an impact.

Comment: Say the video at [projectile motion] (http://www.microsoft.com/germany/aktionen/mach-es-machbar/en-us/default.aspx)  is to start playing  at the same time as the animation  [terminal output simulation] (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37869/beamer-animations-how-to-simulate-terminal-input-and-output)