# Self-scrolling formulas and text in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, equations, animate

For a presentation with Beamer, I would like to have a slide where a long list of formulas (maybe mixed with text) scrolls automatically within a certain part of the slide. This should look like e.g. closing credits in movies.

I have tried the idea from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37869/beamer-animations-how-to-simulate-terminal-input-and-output)
based on `animateinline` from the [animate package](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf), but whenever I use environments like `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`
or commands like `\textcolor{red}{...}` I get an error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]. \end{frame}
```

Ideally, the formulas/the text should be given within the document itself, but if a solution with an external PDF works fine, I'll take it!

Any ideas how that might work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Synopsis:**

```
%put a longer paragraph of text in a box
\newsavebox\lipsumbox
\begin{lrbox}{\lipsumbox}%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
    \strut
    \lipsum
    \strut
  \end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

%scroll the box content within a viewport of limited height
\smoothscroll[autoplay]{\lipsumbox}{0.93\textheight}{400}{25}
```

[image]

**Usage:**

```
\smoothscroll[autoplay]
  {<box number>}       %filled box
  {<viewport height>}
  {<steps>}            %increase to enhance smoothness
  {<steps per sec>}    %adjust scrolling speed (not more than 25)
```

**Complete example:**

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{animate}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{xsavebox}
\newcommand\smoothscroll[5][]{%
  % [#1] autoplay
  % #2 <boxnum>
  % #3 <viewport height>
  % #4 <steps>
  % #5 <steps per sec>
  \edef\mywd{\the\wd#2}%
  \edef\myht{\the\ht#2}%
  \edef\mytht{\the\dimexpr\ht#2+\dp#2\relax}%
  \xsavebox{scrollbox}{\usebox{#2}}% make re-usable PDF XObject
  \edef\portht{\the\dimexpr#3\relax}%
  \begin{animateinline}[#1,width=\mywd,height=\portht,loop]{#5}
    \multiframe{#4}{dRaiseLen=-\myht+\dimexpr(\mytht+\portht)/#4\relax}{%
      \begin{minipage}[b][#3][b]{\mywd}%
        \raisebox{\dRaiseLen}[0pt][0pt]{\thescrollbox}%
      \end{minipage}%
    }%
  \end{animateinline}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}\huge
\newsavebox\lipsumbox
\begin{lrbox}{\lipsumbox}%
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \strut Lipsum:\\

    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{equation}
      E=mc^2
    \end{equation}
    \centerline{* * *}\strut
  \end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\noindent Read this if you can:\\[1ex]
\smoothscroll[autoplay]{\lipsumbox}{0.93\textheight}{400}{25}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for figuring this out for me! Great job.

Comment: This now is giving an error. Can you update the code?
Missing number, treated as zero. ...utoplay]{\mybox}{0.93\textheight}{400}{25}

Comment: @OOzyPal Thank you for reporting! Fixed.

Comment: +1 This is amazing! Should be part of the animate package.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Maybe as an example in the manual. (I am a bit of reluctant to extend the package's interface with specialised commands.)

Comment: Joking: Or creating a new package called "movie credits".