scrollable box in beamer
I wonder if there is a way to have on a beamer slide a sort of scrollable box to show a long code listing (for example, python code).
The approach described here does not seem to work.

which pdf viewer did you use to test?

Skim (I am compiling with sublime)

Try with adobe reader. Animations aren't supported by all readers.

Just tested with Acrobat: It works! However, I would like to scroll it by myself, not automatically. Any clue?

use \smoothscroll[autopause,controls]{\lipsumbox}{0.93\textheight}{400}{25} to get controls which you can use to manually go forwards or backwards

Thanks. Also this works but it is still not what I am searching for :(
I would like just to have a window like in the complete example at this url  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210953/self-scrolling-formulas-and-text-in-beamer

Maybe some animation wizard has a better idea, but I think the animate package is your best bet. Alternatively, split your text across multiple pages and use your pdf viewer in continuous scroll-mode to scroll up or down in your text.

Thanks! I got it.
