# Execute code during beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, code

I am preparing a beamer presentation which includes demo of some `C`, `C++` or similar code. As these are demo, the execution time is very little. I was wondering if it is possible to execute the code within the presentation?

To display the code I am using `minted`. Here is a sample

```
\documentclass[12pt,xcolor=dvipsnames,mathsf]{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{minted}{C}
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a,b;
    return (a+b);
}
\end{minted}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way I can **demonstrate the execution** of this `C` code during the presentation, instead of *uncovering* output?

Thanks in advance!
-- Mike

Comment: Compile it, run executable with `\href{run:...}{Click!}`?

Comment: The code as is doesn't produce any output. So, nothing to uncover anyway.

Comment: @AlexG looks a good attempt. Though at a first thought, it appears to me that I will have to save all the code snippets as individual files and give reference to each of them.

Comment: @AlexG The code I gave above is just for a sample. In my case, it is producing an output, which I would like to demonstrate!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Show the output in the presentation pdf? If yes, would it be an option to run the program beforehand and copy the output in a `\verbatim` or similar? Or show some kind of real-time console/terminal _inside_ the pdf? If yes, that is almost impossible (with Adobe Reader and Javascript you might be able to do some things). Maybe it is an option to just switch (with alt-tab or cmd-tab on Mac) to the terminal window and then back to the pdf?

Comment: @Marijn, its the second one, I want! I would like to give a _realtime_ demo. My query is precisely to avoid _alt-tab_ or similar.

Comment: Teminal input and output can be simulated. What about this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37995

Comment: @AlexG terminal IO simulations appears to complicated. Will have a look at it. In any case, thanks for introducing this completely new way of presentation! Wasnt aware of it...

Answer (score 2):

You can try SageTeX. I dont know anything specific for C/C++, but I am using it for math execution using Sage.

Comment: I think this could be a comment not an answer.

Comment: @Sigur, it **is** an answer, as it answers the question. Secondly I just now checked that one can execute `C`/`C++` code in `sage`. And hence `sagetex` gives a complete solution!

Comment: So, now you checked and confirmed, you could edit and improve the text. You wrote only *try*, so IMHO it is a comment, not an answer. to be an answer you could show how to execute the program, as OP asked.

Comment: IMO this is an answer to the question. It would be good to add example code and example output to it, and then still it does not do what the OP wanted (a real-time demo) - but @user5325 could not know this because that was posted in a comment _after_ this answer was posted.

Comment: sagetex is also unable to "demonstrate the execution of this C code during the presentation, instead of uncovering output" (taken from OP). What sagetex might be able to do is to achieve exactly the latter, uncovering output it generated for you.